# UPDATE/DELETE row in a VIEW made of multiple tables SQL Server/Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, view, multiple-tables

Q: I made a view that is composed of multiple tables with primary keys. I'm using GridView in ASP.NET to UPDATE and DELETE a row in the database. That row is composed of two different tables. How am I going to UPDATE and DELETE it using the GridView in ASP.NET? I'm having a hard time figuring out because every attempt I make, SQL Server says "Cannot update view because it is accessing multiple tables".

It turns out, you cannot auto-generate UPDATE and DELETE statements in the "Choose Data Sourc" of a GridView when a VIEW is composed of multiple tables.

Please help me guys :(

```
    CREATE VIEW [dbo].[viewProcedureWithPrice]
    AS
    SELECT        dbo.[PROCEDURE].ProcedureID, dbo.[PROCEDURE].Name, dbo.[PROCEDURE].Type, dbo.[PROCEDURE].Status, dbo.PRICE_HISTORY.Price, 
                             dbo.PRICE_HISTORY.EffectivityDate
    FROM            dbo.[PROCEDURE] INNER JOIN
                             dbo.PRICE_HISTORY ON dbo.[PROCEDURE].ProcedureID = dbo.PRICE_HISTORY.ProcedureID

    GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PROCEDURE](
    [ProcedureID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Type] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PROCEDURE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProcedureID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PRICE_HISTORY](
    [HistoryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProcedureID] [int] NULL,
    [Price] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [EffectivityDate] [date] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PRICE_HISTORY] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [HistoryID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PRICE_HISTORY]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PRICE_HISTORY_PROCEDURE] FOREIGN KEY([ProcedureID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PROCEDURE] ([ProcedureID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PRICE_HISTORY] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PRICE_HISTORY_PROCEDURE]
GO
```

Comment: This approach is old-school, but you could always use the ObjectDataSource object, it lets you drill-down into your objects and pick the specific table for that "oDS" which will in-turn allow you to create the required "CRUD" statements to automagically handle basic Create-Read-Update-Delete (CRUD) functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, what I have done is add my own delete button in the row with a different command name, say "MyDelete" (maybe add the appropriate command argument to identify the row or use DataKeys).  Catch it in the GridView_RowCommand event and perform your deletes manually there.

Maybe there's a better way, but this works.

I'd have to see the code to go into greater detail.